# Image size is reduced in Google Static Map using API key

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

My Google Static Maps image size is reduced into 640x400px using API key too.
By [official docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Imagesizes), google should enable the 2048px width image size, when you use API key.
My current image `src` tag is `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&size=2048x400&zoom=14&key=AIzaSyDtQgHRpKBnlCfmlFyIKhliytfCb9tHgJY`
(I will regenerate the API key, you can use for testing purposes)

- The API key is OK.
- The Google Static Maps API  is **enabled**
- The Google Developer Console shows the requests amount (it is comunicate)

Does anyobody have idea what Im doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Just tried that URL and it worked. You might want to restrict your API key to your IP address only to avoid any unnecessary usage spikes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The possible size doesn't  depend on the usage of a key, it's depends on the used license.

You'll need a **Google Maps API for Work**-license to be able to get the desired image.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Imagesizes):

```
API                         scale=1     scale=2     scale=4
Free                        640x640     640x640     Not available.
                                        (returns 
                                        1280x1280 
                                        pixels) 

Google Maps API for Work    2048x2048   1024x1024   512x512 
                                        (returns    (returns 
                                        2048x2048   2048x2048 
                                        pixels)     pixels)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea where can I get this license?

Comment: https://www.google.com/work/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html?rd=1#display=cs-dialog-form

Comment: Thank you, I will make a try.